# Mostrar una activity en la lock screen desde una notificación

Tags: java, android, activity, notificaciones

quiero mostrar una activity que se inicia desde una notificación. Si la pantalla de bloqueo (lockscreen) no es segura (deslizar) consigo el comportamiento deseado.

En cambio, si la pantalla de bloqueo es segura (con pin o código) obliga al usuario a introducir el código de desbloqueo.

Sé que llamando el activity directo desde la notificación Android no lo permite, he leido en otras respuestas de SOgeneral que si lo llamas desde un intentService si. Pero a mi no me funciona. En el manifest le doy los permisos correspondientes.

## Códigos

NotificacitonService (solo método, se inicia en el onCreate)

```
public void crearNotificacion(){
    RemoteViews rmv = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.notification_custom);

    /*Intent intent = new Intent(this, wPerfil.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 54, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);*/
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,NotificationIntentService.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,54,intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    createNotificationChannel();// Este trozo de codigo es para versiones +26
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setCustomContentView(rmv)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_trasnparent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .setGroupSummary(false)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    startForeground(intentID,builder.build());

}
```

NotificationIntentService

```
  @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        handleNotfication();
    }
}


private void handleNotfication(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,wPerfil.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Activity a mostrar

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
        setShowWhenLocked(true);
        setTurnScreenOn(true);
    }else{
       getWindow().addFlags(
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_w_perfil);
}
```

Si necesitais mas código o algo preguntar.

Comment: No me queda claro cual es el problema. Cuando el usuario tenga codigo de bloqueo, siempre le va a pedir el codigo para desbloquearse, sino seria un agujero de seguridad.

Comment: El problema es que necesito mostrar en la lockScreen esa activity sin desbloquear la pantalla cuando el usuario pulsa en la notificación. He probado con widgets lockscreen pero me resulta mas que complicado. He conseguido sacar la activity a la lockscreen haciendo la notificación fullScreen, pero no me sirve ese conportamiento porque no se ejecuta cuando yo quiero que es al pulsar en la notificación y la fullScreen se ejecuta cuando se crea el servicio en el mainActivity.

Comment: @Schwarz54 revisa las flags que defino en mi respuesta para abrir la Activity aún estando cerrado el dispositivo.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas mostrar la Activity cuando tu dispositivo se encuentra bloqueado lo puedes realizar mediante este método, el cual se define despúes de `setContentView()`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

   }
```

Ahora si deseas mostrar esta Activity desde la notificación,

[Cómo iniciar una actividad desde una notificación](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation)

Lo realizas mediante un PendingIntent:

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
// Set the Activity to start in a new, empty task
notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
// Create the PendingIntent
PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);
```

Comment: Esto todo ya lo logro si la pantalla de bloqueo no es segura (no tiene pin o código). Respecto a tu primer código, es el que ejecuto en la activity a mostrar, sin el dissmiskeyguard porque no quiero desbloquear el movil, y respecto a tu segundo código, lo tengo comentado en mi servicio porque no funciona, pide desbloqueo de pantalla (cuando es segura).

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

hola esto me funciona pero hay en ciertos dispositivos que no como los de marca
samsung y huawei